# Why dynamic memory allocation functions in C returns void*?

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the prototypes of C's dynamic allocation functions

```
malloc - void* malloc(size_t size);

calloc -  void* calloc(size_t n,size);

realloc - void* realloc(void* ptr,size_t newsize);
```

Now a statement like following

```
int* p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

I know that casting to (int*) isn't needed in C since a void pointer can be assigned to a pointer variable of any object type, but why these functions by default not return fully typed pointer?. Wouln't it be nice if it returns int* instead of void pointer in this case? What is the reason void* is choosen as return type of these functions?

One other question: I've read [here](http://pweb.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch9x.htm) that in older C compilers the type of pointer returned by these functions was **char*** not **void***. Is it true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does void in C mean not void?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/254181/31260)

Comment: This is because these methods are allocating memory without any specific type.  If `malloc` returned `int*` and you allocate only 1 byte, you would never be able to dereference it safely without casting.

Comment: in C, it is a bad idea to have any casting at all when assigning the returned pointer from malloc (and family of functions)

Comment: Questions are related but I am not convinced this is a duplicate. Having written the accepted answer on the dupe target, it would add insight to this question but I do not believe it would answer it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Because it can't.**

How would it return a fully typed pointer? C doesn't have templates/generics, and it doesn't allow function overloading; let alone overloading by return type only. So there's no mechanism to have a `malloc` that knew what type you wanted.

> I've read here that in older C compilers the type of pointer returned by these functions was char* not void*. Is it true?

In C, there is no `byte`. `char` is guaranteed to be a byte long, so `char*` is canonical "a pointer to some byte buffer", which is exactly what memory allocation functions want to return.

Comment: conceptually, the returned value from malloc is a char pointer.  However, that creates problems when needing to assign that pointer to some other type, such as a struct pointer.   'void', a relatively new keyword, eliminates the need for casting (and makes casting error prone, especially when performing maintenance on the code)

Comment: @user3629249: No, conceptually it's a pointer to a new uninitialized memory-block, and you haven't decided what it should contain.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add that `malloc` returned `char*` in the time before `void*` were invented. Once `void*` existed, the signature of `malloc` was quickly adjusted to follow suit.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: It's too bad that C reused the "void" term from functions rather than adding an "untyped memory chunk" type which would allow the free casting of void*, but could also be read and written like "char*".  That would allow code to exploit platforms whose minimal addressable unit is smaller than 8 bits and avoid the need to cast untyped memory pointers to char* before using them.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `malloc()` could return a fully typed pointer.  The problem is, of what type?  If it returned an `int*`, it would make you happy, but it would not make me happy, because I want a `char*` instead.  Clearly, we could not both have it our way.  So, `void*` is a good baseline which does not take anyone's side.